# Is there a way to get an RSS feed of the "Unanswered Questions" feed?

Tags: feature-request

I don't see a link or anything in the HTML ... any way to get an RSS feed of the "Unanswered Questions" section from the Wordpress Answers site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would that work? **Every** question is unanswered right after it is created. Such feed would be no different from generic recent questions feed.

Comment: Haha that's a good point. I guess in reality I was looking for what you call the "generic recent questions feed" - which I think I found at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds correct?

Comment: @GavinR yep....